Compact Low RPM Motor
Are there any electric motors that are designed to operate optimally (smooth and high torque) around 1 - 10 RPM speeds without the help of external or integrated reducers like gears? As far as I know the optimal RPM range of stepper motors is in the hundreds, and of brushed / brushless DC motors is in the thousands. Not sure about the AC, synchronous, and direct drive motors though, but they don't seem to be available in compact sizes of less than 2 - 3 inches anyway. I've heard about piezoelectric motors but couldn't find a place that sells them.

How much torque are we talking about? Buy one of these, take it apart and you will find a very low speed, high torque motor without gearbox. Brushed DC, very long and narrow. https://www.directindustry.com/prod/atlas-copco-tools/product-8006-2280312.html

A BLDC motor can go right down to zero speed if driven like a micro-stepping stepper, though the zero speed torque is no more than their rated torque at speed, so power output is low at low speeds.

("BLDC motors" are synchronous (electro-magnetic) machines, plus a DC->multiphase converter)

Does it have to be an electric motor?  Prehaps an air or hydraulic motor can satisfy your needs.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні It does, but I'm curious about the hydraulic motors, can you get them in comparable sizes to the NEMA 17 or 23 motors?

Probably not, unless you're shopping in the wrong catalogs.
An electric motor is limited by physics.  At the low-speed torque end of the performance envelope, the physics involved are the strength of the magnetic field that can be generated by permanent magnets or field windings, times the field generated by armature windings, the diameter of the motor, and its length.
The limit to how much torque can be generated is whether the windings will melt or burn up, and whether the magnets will demagnetize.  There's not much you can do to get away from these limits with the materials that humans have available to us today.
If you have a motor of a given size, then if you keep the design generally the same you can increase its torque production capability roughly linearly to the length of its magnetic gap, and roughly as the square of the diameter of the magnetic gap.
To get more power out of a motor, once this low-speed torque limit is reached, you just need to spin it faster, and gear it down.
